# Create a temporary table inside procedure and delete from event

Tags: mysql, events, stored-procedures

I have a procedure like this :

```
create
    procedure new_generation(IN id bigint unsigned)
BEGIN
    create temporary table if not exists tmp_mine
    (
        id         bigint unsigned primary key  not null auto_increment,
        created_at timestamp,
    );
end
```

now I want to create an event for delete old rows.

```
create event per_ten_second on schedule
    every '10' SECOND
        starts '2021-10-26 11:49:16'
    enable
    do
    delete from tmp_mine where created_at < now();
```

but it doesn't work. Can anybody give me a clue? Can we use generated temp table inside stored procedure out of it? for example inside an event.

Comment: Temporary tables are only visible in the session that created them. What is it you are trying to do with the temporary table, e.g. can you use just a normal table?

Comment: @Solarflare I want to control concurrency access. For example two users in same time want to buy an object, so I add that  object's id in a temp table. before start a process on objects check exists in temp or not. I wanted to be fast so I decided to use from temp table.

Comment: Temporary tables are not faster than normal tables, just start with one of those, test it and try to optimize when you realize it is slower than you need (it probably won't be, and the solution won't be using temporary tables, but probably indexes). (Also, you may want to rethink the design of reserving articles, e.g. you could just have a column "reserved until" in your "shoppingcart" table, then you do not need an event to clear it up, and can just check/sum currently active articles. But that's a different topic.)